# Can an integrable function on an interval have jump discontinuities?

Tags: integration, derivatives, riemann-integration

So I was wondering about this question

***An integrable function on an interval cannot have jumps.***

I always thought that a differentiable function on an interval cannot have jumps, so i was thinking that also an integrable function on an interval cannot have jumps.

Am i correct?

Moreover, If the derivative does not exist at a point, then this critical point cannot be either a local maximum or a local minimum. This question is false; correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 1):

No. The function$$\begin{array}{ccc}[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\t&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }t<0\\1&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\end{array}$$is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: So this implies that an integrable function CAN indeed have jumps?

Comment: @MichaelMorello Is. My function is such an example, right?!

Comment: yes sure, thank you . What about the fact that if the derivative does not exist at a point, then this critical point cannot be either a local maximum or a local minimum. This question is false, right? A critical point , which is a point where the derivative can be undefined/doesn't exist, can be a local max/min , right?

Comment: @MichaelMorello We generally like posts to contain only a single question. It would be better if you made a separate post about the other question. But before you do, take a look at the graph of $f(x) = |x|$, and see what you think.

Answer (score 0):

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) that a bounded function on a closed and bounded interval is Riemann integrable over that interval iff the set of points where it is discontinuous has measure $0$. A jump discontinuity happens at a single point, and a set containing a single point has measure $0$. The type of discontinuity is irrelevant to the theorem.

Comment: What about the second question ?e.g  f(x) = |x| has its (local and absolute) minimum value at 0, but f'(x) = 0 does not exist. So this would imply that the statement is false. Please please please tell me. Unfortunately, i can't do any more questions.... It would be of great use as im starting my maths course now